# How to use libraries from Quicklisp in Common Lisp source code?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I am trying to program a tcp server using Common Lisp (sbcl) on Windows-11. My main goal is to create a stand alone executable tcp server.
So, I am using the `usocket` library (loading it with `(ql:quickload "usocket")`) to create the server socket. It performing without any issues when I am writing the codes inside of the REPL, but when I am using it in source code, named `Server.lisp` and try to run using the `sbcl --script Server.lisp` it shows this error:

```
Unhandled SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD in thread
#<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010A8003}>:
READ error during LOAD:
Package QL does not exist.
Line: 1, Column: 12, File-Position: 12
```

Comment: `--script` does not load the init files. If your init file loads quicklisp, then this is not happening. You would need to load them yourself. See the SBCL documentation: https://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Toplevel-Options

Comment: You can use `--load`, and call `(uiop:quit)` yourself from inside your main function (otherwise you will get the lisp REPL, which is sometimes nice sometimes not what we want), or `--eval (uiop:quit)`.

Comment: You can take reference from [plain-common-lisp](https://github.com/pascalcombier/plain-common-lisp).